# golang case called by other case do not execute but return

Tags: go

Why `Stopped` isnt print out, and return the `main` instead?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    var stop chan int = make(chan int)
    for {
        select {
        case <- stop:
            fmt.Println("Stopped!")
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Println("tick.")
        case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            stop <- 0
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
BOOM!
```

Expect:

```
   .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
BOOM!
Stopped!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements) says the following about sending to a channel:

> Communication blocks until the send can proceed. A send on an
>   unbuffered channel can proceed if a receiver is ready. A send on a
>   buffered channel can proceed if there is room in the buffer.

So when your code gets to `stop <- 0` it blocks waiting for another goroutine to read from the channel and this never happens (your `case <- stop:` is within the same go routine so is not active).

There are a few ways you can solve this:

1. Use a buffered channel (e.g. `stop := make(chan int, 1)`).
2. Wait for the stop in another go routine ([example](https://play.golang.org/p/P9p7xMJZJ6t))
3. Close the channel instead of sending something to it (`close(stop)`).

Note: Due to the way your application is written none of these options will actually stop it because your for loop never exits (add a `break` or `return` to exit).

Comment: "if a receiver is ready" basically means the send can proceed when another goroutine is attempting to receive from the channel (e.g. via ```<- stop```).

Comment: I should add that the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types) says "A channel provides a mechanism for concurrently executing functions to communicate by sending and receiving values of a specified element type". In your program you have 3 go routines (main, one started by time.Tick and one started by time.After). As your ```stop``` is only used within the main routine (and, as such, only communicating with itself) you don't need a channel for that; see this [alternative implementation](https://play.golang.org/p/n62LQNKJ6X7).

Answer (score 3):

When BOOM happens the main goroutine stsrts waiting to write to stop channel. But there are no other goroutines waiting to read from it so it is a deadlock.

If you make stop channel a buffered channel with capacity 1 then it will be able to write to it and next iteration will read. Or simply close the channel.

Answer (score 0):

@Jiburiru this works.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    tick := time.Tick(100 * time.Millisecond)
    boom := time.After(500 * time.Millisecond)
    stop := make(chan int)
    for {
        select {
        case <-stop:
            fmt.Println("Stopped!")
            return
        case <-tick:
            fmt.Println("tick.")
        case <-boom:
            fmt.Println("BOOM!")
            close(stop)
        default:
            fmt.Println("    .")
            time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Output follows.

```
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
    .
    .
tick.
BOOM!
Stopped!
```